# Put constraints on Decision Tree / Random Forest

Tags: scikit-learn

I have some features that I want 
to put on top on the generated trees
(Tree constraints).

Reason is those features are imposed feature
(Physical), event it may result
in loss of accuracy, need to put
as hard constraint.

How can we do in Scikit Learn ?

Comment: Maybe you can put your constrains after you get the DT predictions?

Comment: Yes, we can prune after. But, the search space is big, we can select before, it will accelerate the generation.